# remain constant vs remain the same

Tags: word-choice, difference

A native speaker wrote the below sentence as a sample sentence for me to study. According to the dictionary, "constant" means occurring continuously over a period of time. But there are only two data points and two years in the pie charts, so I wonder if "constant" is not good here. Would it be better to say "remained **unchanged/the same**"

> Expenditure on buildings and transport remained **constant** at 17%.

[image]

Comment: Sure, you could say it like that.

Comment: Thank you. But my problem is that I think "constant" is wrong here because there are only two data points. I think "constant" is for a lot of data points. Is "constant" wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right in that there is some sense of 'continuity' rather than a single data point.

Compare opening a tap [US faucet] to maintain a *constant* flow, to filling a pint glass then resting it down. The tap releases an ever-increasing amount of water, the glass remains *the same*.

I think, though, that in your example it could be claimed that buildings & transport expenditure remains *constant* between the two data points. One could extrapolate & be right or wrong… but then we're into the realm of prediction & statistics.
In this simple 2-point analysis, you could equally say it was constant, or that it was unchanged or remained the same.
The two are close enough that you *can* blur the distinction, though personally in this instance I'd prefer to remove the sense of continuity & use 'unchanged' or 'the same'.